# Return second smallest number in a nested list using recursion

Tags: python, algorithm, list, recursion

I have to return the **second smallest** number in a python list using recursion, and **no loops**. What I have done is created a helper function that returns a tuple of the (smallest, second smallest) values in the list, and then I just take the `tuple[1]` in my `second_smallest` func.

```
def s_smallest(L):

    if(len(L) == 2):
        if (L[0] >= L[1]):
            return (L[1],L[0])
        else:
            return (L[0],L[1])
    else:
        first_smallest,second_smallest = s_smallest(L[1:])

        if L[0] >= first_smallest and L[0] <= second_smallest:
            return (first_smallest, L[0])

        elif L[0] <= first_smallest:
            return (L[0], first_smallest)

        else:
            return (first_smallest, second_smallest)
```

This works, but now I need to handle **nested lists**, so `s_smallest([1,2,[3,0]])` should return `(0,1)`. I tried doing this:

```
if isinstance(L[0],list):
    first_smallest,second_smallest = s_smallest(L[0])
else:
    first_smallest,second_smallest = s_smallest(L[1:])
```

to get the first smallest and second smallest values if it is a list, but I get an error saying `builtins.TypeError: unorderable types: int() >= list()`. How can I fix this problem to deal with nested lists?

Comment: The obvious source of your error is that you didn't finish integrating that code. If L[0] is a list, then you have to recurse on it and then continue processing with L[1]. You can't use L[0] any more, *because it's a list, not an integer*. You're on the right track, though. Try something like `l0,l1 = s_smallest(L[0]); m0,m1=s_smallest(L[1:]);` then merge l0,l1,m0,m1

Comment: Also, beware of the possibility (as in your example) that when `len(L)==2` there might still be a list or two involved. You probably should recurse all the way down, and handle `None` or something for the len=1 case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I might suggest separating the list unnesting and the min reducing into two separate, well-defined tasks

- `deepReduce` will reduce a list of lists using the specified reducing function
- `deepMin` performs a `deepReduce` using `min`

```py
import math # used for math.inf

def min (x,y):
  return x if x < y else y

def deepReduce (f, y, xs):
  if not xs:
    return y
  elif isinstance(xs[0], list):
    return deepReduce(f, deepReduce(f, y, xs[0]), xs[1:])
  else:
    return deepReduce(f, f(y, xs[0]), xs[1:])

def deepMin (xs):
  return deepReduce (min, math.inf, xs)


data = [1,2,[7,[6,1,3,[0,4,3]],3,4],2,1]
print(deepMin(data))
# 0
```

Oh, but you said you want the *second* smallest number. Let's rework that code a little bit. Of course I knew that all along, but answering this question twice allows me to demonstrate the versatility of this specific implementation – Changes in **bold**

```
def min2 (xs, y):
  # x1 is the smallest, x2 is second smallest
  x1, x2 = xs
  if (y < x1) and (y < x2):
    return (y, x2)
  elif y < x2:
    return (x1, y)
  else:
    return (x1, x2)

def deepMin2 (xs):
  # notice we change to use tuple of math.inf now
  x1, x2 = deepReduce (min2, (math.inf, math.inf), xs)
  return x2

data = [1,2,[7,[6,1,3,[0,4,3]],3,4],2,1]
print(deepMin2(data))
# 1
```

I should point out that we didn't have to touch `deepReduce` at all, which is the point – we should be able to do any arbitrary deep operation on our nested list without having to statically code that behaviour into our function.

Now you can write whatever deep reducer you want and call it with `deepReduce`

Comment: This is a great solution but is it possible to do without importing anything?

Comment: Just using basic python?

Comment: Well the `math` module is included with python... but if you must introduce arbitrary limitations like that, replace `math.inf` with a "really big" number.

Comment: Another option is replacing `math.inf` with `None` and writing another condition inside `min2` to check for `None` before doing `<` comparisons

Answer (score 0):

## Full solution

Using nothing but `functools.reduce`, no loops, to handle lists of arbitrary nesting:

```
import functools

def helper(acc, x):
    if type(x) is list:
        return functools.reduce(lambda acc, x: helper(acc, x), x, acc)
    else:
        if x < acc[0]:
            return (x, acc[0])
        elif x < acc[1]:
            return (acc[0], x)
        else:
            return (acc[0], acc[1])

def second_smallest(l):
    if len(l) < 2:
        return None
    else:
        if l[0] <= l[1]:
            return functools.reduce(lambda acc, x: helper(acc, x), l[2:], (l[0], l[1]))
        else:
            return functools.reduce(lambda acc, x: helper(acc, x), l[2:], (l[1], l[0]))

>>> second_smallest([1,2,[0,3,[-1,-2]]])
(-2, -1)
```